# How to use the -e/-E option for p4 labels

Tags: perforce

I tried to use "p4 labels" to retrieve labels with names of format "FOO_2.4.4". I tried the following list of things but none of them works. On the other hand "p4 labels .... | grep FOO" did get me the labels. Is there anything I missed?

- p4 labels -e FOO
- p4 labels -e FOO ....
- p4 labels -e FOO //comms/path_to_directory_containing_files_in_label/...
- p4 labels -e "FOO"
- p4 labels -e "FOO" ....
- p4 labels -e "FOO" //comms/path_to_directory_containing_files_in_label/...
- p4 labels -E FOO
- p4 labels -E FOO ....
- p4 labels -E FOO //comms/path_to_directory_containing_files_in_label/...
- p4 labels -E "FOO"
- p4 labels -E "FOO" ....
- p4 labels -E "FOO" //comms/path_to_directory_containing_files_in_label/...
- p4 labels -e FOO*
- p4 labels -e FOO* ....
- p4 labels -e FOO* //comms/path_to_directory_containing_files_in_label/...
- p4 labels -e "FOO*"
- p4 labels -e "FOO*" ....
- p4 labels -e "FOO*" //comms/path_to_directory_containing_files_in_label/...
- p4 labels -E FOO*
- p4 labels -E FOO* ....
- p4 labels -E FOO* //comms/path_to_directory_containing_files_in_label/...
- p4 labels -E "FOO*"
- p4 labels -E "FOO*" ....
- p4 labels -E "FOO*" //comms/path_to_directory_containing_files_in_label/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going wrong. It may be an issue with quoting. On my Windows command line shell, I have to use double quotes, not single quotes:

```
C:\Users\Bryan>p4 tag -l FOO_2.4.4 //...
//depot/a#1 - added

C:\Users\Bryan>p4 labels -e 'FOO*'

C:\Users\Bryan>p4 labels -e "FOO*"
Label FOO_2.4.4 2014/09/03 'Created by Bryan.'
```

But it seems that you have tried several combinations of quotes with no success.

Did you also try -E? That makes the matching case-insensitive.

Comment: Yes, I tried -E, no success. And p4 command line client does not print any version information.

Comment: The problem might be quite specific to your data set. Have you contacted Perforce Technical Support?

Comment: Thanks for helping out, Bryan. It turned out all I need to do is turning off my computer and turning it on again after a weekend.